# How to animate modal overlay (background opacity) in React native navigation using Native Stack?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-navigation

I have previously used regular Stack navigator from `@react-navigation/stack`, i've decided to migrate to Native Stack from `@react-navigation/native-stack`, but `cardStyleInterpolator` doesn't exist as an option in Native Stacks, which i've used for animating background colour opacity with screen transition progress:

```js
const forVertical = ({
  current,
  inverted,
  layouts: { screen },
}: StackCardInterpolationProps) => {
  const translateY = multiply(
    current.progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [screen.height, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
    inverted,
  );

  const overlayOpacity = current.progress.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
    outputRange: [0, 0.85, 0.85],
  });
  return {
    cardStyle: {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY,
        },
      ],
    },
    overlayStyle: {
      opacity: overlayOpacity,
    },
  };
};
```

which i've used as `cardStyleInterpolator`

I've found a workaround for the slide from bottom animation  using

```js
presentation: 'transparentModal',
animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
```

Which results in a correct behaviour for modal presenting
What's left is just animating the background opacity, that's what i'm struggling with.
Is this possible somehow using Native Stack only without using `cardStyleInterpolator`?

here's Snack with example of what i've had and what i'm trying to achieve: https://snack.expo.dev/@oleksii_shevchenko/calm-orange-nachos